# arcmap - automatically change name of map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I would like to insert text place in arcmap with street name. For every I have to plot one map. I have hundreds of them in shp file and it would be great to avoid one by one manual typing street name.
Attribute table contain name for particular street i.e.:

[image]

I do not want to place one by one name of the street, then plot, move to next street area, change name, plot etc.
Is it possible to autoamatically change name of street in txt when I have different area in Layout Viev?

Comment: Do you want a script-based solution (you have the `python` tag)?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is a combination of [data driven pages](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#/What_are_Data_Driven_Pages/00s90000003m000000/) and [dynamic text](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//00s900000039000000).

[image: Esri screenshot of Data Driven Pages setup]

In your case, you'd set the "Name Field" as your street names (e.g. `STREET_NAME`).

Then, insert dynamic text that refers to that property in your map layout.

```
<dyn type="page" property="name"/>
```

This will also enable you to automatically cycle through dozens or hundreds of street maps *very quickly* if you're exporting to PDF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Erica. Is it possible using at this moment (please check below) using Data Driven Pages automatically adjusting angle to the print frame area before exporting to pdf? I have blocks (a3 format, 1:1000 scale) where each is in different angle.

[image]